# Add dropdown button to plotly express choropleth map

Tags: plotly, plotly-python, choropleth, plotly-express

I already saw this and i am trying to build off this solution ([Dropdown menu for Plotly Choropleth Map Plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61750811/dropdown-menu-for-plotly-choropleth-map-plots#))  but I keep getting errors for the visible section, here is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px

# Data
cols_dd = ["Total tests", "Total cases", "Total deaths"]
# 
visible = np.array(cols_dd)

# define traces and buttons at once
traces = []
buttons = []
for value in cols_dd:
    traces.append(px.choropleth(df,
       locations="Iso code", # Spatial coordinates
        color=value, # Data to be color-coded
        hover_data={'Iso code':False, 'Vaccines':True, 'Total tests':': ,0.f', 'Recent cases':': ,0.f', 'Total cases':': ,0.f','Total deaths':': ,0.f','Total vaccinations':': ,0.f','People vaccinated':': ,0.f','Population':': ,0.f','Vaccination policy':': 0.f'},
        color_continuous_scale="spectral_r",
        hover_name="Location",)).update_traces(visible= True if value==cols_dd[0] else False)

buttons.append(dict(label=value, method="update", args=[{"visible":list(visible==value)}, {"title":f"<b>{value}</b>"}]))

updatemenus = [{"active":0,"buttons":buttons}]

layout = go.Layout(
    showlegend=True,
    font=dict(size=12),
    width = 800,
    height = 500,
    margin=dict(l=0,r=0,b=0,t=40)
    )


# Show figure
fig = go.Figure(data=traces, layout=dict(updatemenus=updatemenus))
# This is in order to get the first title displayed correctly
first_title = cols_dd[0]
fig.update_layout(layout)
fig.update_geos(scope="africa")
fig.update_layout(title=f"<b>{first_title}</b>",title_x=0.5)
fig.show()
```

I get the error message 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update_traces', also if its possible to get the fix for dash, that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you have any data that I can try in my environment? Also, shouldn't visible be included in choropleth?

Comment: Just counties iso_code and random numbers for each column will do, e.g here are some iso codes for country ZWE, ZMB, UGA, TUN, TGO. as for the visible thats where i am having issues using it with plotly express not graph objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- OWID data is pretty much what you are using.  Column names are a little different so renamed to use
- fundamentally, be systematic on how you build traces and layout
- have created a **colorbar** config for each trace to ensure it's more responsive
- extended **cols_dd** to show how it can be used for plotting more metrics
- as per comments included scatter as well as choropleth

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import itertools

# get OWID data
df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/latest/owid-covid-latest.csv"
)
# rename columns as sample code uses other names....
df = df.rename(
    columns={
        "location": "Location",
        "iso_code": "Iso code",
        "total_tests": "Total tests",
        "people_vaccinated_per_hundred": "Vaccines",
        "new_cases": "Recent cases",
        "total_cases": "Total cases",
        "total_deaths": "Total deaths",
        "total_vaccinations": "Total vaccinations",
        "people_vaccinated": "People vaccinated",
        "population": "Population",
        "total_boosters": "Vaccination policy",
    }
).fillna(0)
cols_dd = ["Total tests", "Total cases", "Total deaths", "Recent cases", "new_deaths"]
hd = {
    "Iso code": False,
    "Vaccines": True,
    "Total tests": ": ,0.f",
    "Recent cases": ": ,0.f",
    "Total cases": ": ,0.f",
    "Total deaths": ": ,0.f",
    "Total vaccinations": ": ,0.f",
    "People vaccinated": ": ,0.f",
    "Population": ": ,0.f",
    "Vaccination policy": ": 0.f",
}

fig = go.Figure()

for i, value in enumerate(cols_dd):
    # use a different color axis for each trace... makes it more responsive
    ca = f"coloraxis{i+2}"

    figc = px.choropleth(
        df,
        locations="Iso code",  # Spatial coordinates
        color=value,  # Data to be color-coded
        hover_data=hd,
        color_continuous_scale="spectral_r",
        hover_name="Location",
    ).update_traces(visible=False, coloraxis=ca)
    figs = px.scatter_geo(
        df,
        locations="Iso code",  # Spatial coordinates
        color=value,  # Data to be color-coded
        hover_data=hd,
        color_continuous_scale="spectral_r",
        hover_name="Location",
    ).update_traces(visible=False, marker={"coloraxis": ca})

    fig = fig.add_traces(figc.data)
    fig = fig.add_traces(figs.data)
    fig = fig.update_layout(
        {
            ca: {
                "cmin": df[value].replace(0, np.nan).quantile(0.25),
                "cmax": df[value].replace(0, np.nan).quantile(0.75),
                "colorbar": {"title": value},
            }
        }
    )


fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": f"{m} - {p}",
                    "method": "update",
                    "args": [
                        {
                            "visible": [
                                (m2 == m and p2 == p)
                                for m2, p2 in itertools.product(
                                    cols_dd, ["choropleth", "scatter"]
                                )
                            ]
                        },
                        {"title": f"<b>{m}</b>"},
                    ],
                }
                for m, p in itertools.product(cols_dd, ["choropleth", "scatter"])
            ]
        }
    ],
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 25, "b": 0},
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much rob, this worked beautifully well, please is it possible i bother you with one more question.... if i wanted to repeat the same process on a scatter plot but using 2 drop down where I can switch between variables (e.g Total tests and Total cases, or Recent cases and Total cases )  on both sides, can you please share me a sample solution. i have tried replacing this (cols_dd = ["Total tests", "Total cases", "Total deaths"] ) with a dictionary and this ( for value in cols_dd: ) with for k,v in cols_dd.items(): and the using k and v in place of values but it returns an error.

Comment: have updated - case of creating more traces and control visibility with list in **updatemenus**

Comment: Thank you for your time and response, however i did not mean in a choropleth map, i meant in  attempting to build a completely different scatter plot. i have asked the question with better example and explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69242033/build-a-plotly-scatterplot-with-two-drop-down-buttons-one-for-x-and-one-for-y-ax

Comment: on my first question i am completely satisfied and grateful.

Comment: I've answered the second question,  if these answers meet you question, consider following SO etiquette and accepting answers