# Update plotly color_discrete_map on choropleth map using buttons

Tags: plotly, choropleth

Choropleth map don't update after selecting drop down button.

A sample data would be having a true or false Boolean on each vaccine brand name for all 50 countries.

Here is my code.

```
cols_dd = ["Johnson&Johnson","Sinopharm","Sputnik V","Moderna","AstraZeneca","Pfizer","Sinovac","Covaxin"]


fig = go.Figure()

for value in cols_dd:
    fig.add_traces(
        px.choropleth(
            df,
            locations="Iso code",  # Spatial coordinates
            color=value,  # Data to be color-coded
            hover_data={'Iso code':False},
            color_continuous_scale="spectral_r",
            hover_name="Location",
            color_discrete_map={True: 'blue', False: 'white'})
        
        .update_traces(visible= True if value==cols_dd[0] else False)
        .data
    )

fig.update_geos(scope="africa")
fig.update_layout(showlegend=True, font=dict(size=12), width = 800, height = 650, margin=dict(l=0,r=0,b=0,t=70),
    title= "<b>Vaccination Brands and Statistics Across Africa</b>",

    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": value,
                    "method": "update",
                    "args": [
                        {"visible": [v2 == value for v2 in cols_dd]},
                        #{"title": f"<b>{value}</b>"},
                    ],
                }
                for value in cols_dd
            ]
        }
    ]
)
```

it is expected that once i select each vaccine the color code should update on the map but it don't happen correctly, please help. also please help put the button on top center instead of aligned to the left.

Answer (score 0):

- the primary issue is that you are not considering that two traces are created for each vaccine (for `True` and `False` discrete values).  Have named the traces and then used that in **updatemenus**
- button positioning is fully documented here https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/updatemenus/

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

dfloc = pd.read_html(
    "https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/blob/master/public/data/vaccinations/locations.csv"
)[0]

df = dfloc.loc[:, ["iso_code", "location"]].join(
    dfloc["vaccines"]
    .apply(lambda s: pd.Series({v.strip(): True for v in s.split(",")}))
    .fillna(False)
)

cols_dd = ["Johnson&Johnson","Sinopharm","Sputnik V","Moderna","AstraZeneca","Pfizer","Sinovac","Covaxin"]
# OWID names are a little different. Use OWID name when it overlaps with OP name...
cols_dd = [
    c for c in df.select_dtypes(include=bool).columns if any(m in c for m in cols_dd)
]
fig = go.Figure()

for value in cols_dd:
    fig.add_traces(
        px.choropleth(
            df,
            locations="iso_code",  # Spatial coordinates
            color=value,  # Data to be color-coded
            hover_data={"iso_code": False},
            color_continuous_scale="spectral_r",
            hover_name="location",
            color_discrete_map={True: "blue", False: "grey"},
        )
        .update_traces(meta=value, visible=True if value == cols_dd[0] else False)
        .data
    )


fig.update_geos(scope="africa")
fig.update_layout(
    showlegend=True,
    font=dict(size=12),
    width=800,
    height=650,
    margin=dict(l=0, r=0, b=0, t=70),
    title="<b>Vaccination Brands and Statistics Across Africa</b>",
    legend=dict(yanchor="top",y=1,xanchor="center",x=0.5, orientation="h"),
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "x": 0.5,
            "xanchor": "center",
            "y": 1.05,
            "yanchor": "top",
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": value,
                    "method": "update",
                    "args": [
                        {"visible": [t.meta == value for t in fig.data]},
                        # {"title": f"<b>{value}</b>"},
                    ],
                }
                for value in cols_dd
            ],
        }
    ],
)
```

Comment: thank you for the solution @rob, however give that its a true or false situation, I will like for a second button that selects to update for when true or false, e.g. when I select "Sinopharm" using the first button i should be able to use the second button to select for whether true or false. i understand that this is outside the scope of my original question but the help will be much appreciated as I am relatively new to this and trying to learning from every chance, before commenting I already tried a few ways, i even tried creating a new fig and updating the menus.

Comment: that is actually built into the plotly capability.  you can select / unselect from the legend

Comment: have updated layout to move legend to center top under menu. plus changed color